# Airflow Failed To Import Plugin for a plugin folder with custom name

Tags: airflow

I have to work on a shared Airflow 1.10 project, so I have cloned the repository and the structure is as follow:

```
airflow
├── airflow.cfg
├── airflow.db
├── dags
│   ├── dags_here.py
│      
├── dags_conf
│   ├── some settings for dags
│   │   └── settings.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   └── todo.txt
|   |__ init.py
|
├── utilities
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── some_name
│       ├── airflow
│       │   └── hooks.py
            └── sensors.py
            └── plugins.py
│       ├── common
│       │   ├some_other_code_files.py
│       ├── __init__.py
|
├── README.md
├── unittests.cfg
└── venv
    ├── lib64 -> lib
    └── pyvenv.cfg
```

But when I try to list dags I face this error:

> plugins_manager.py:225} ERROR - No module named 'common' Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/xxx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/plugins_manager.py",
> line 218, in 
> m = imp.load_source(namespace, filepath)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
> module = _load(spec)   File "", line 702, in _load   File "", line 671, in
> _load_unlocked   File "", line 783, in exec_module   File "", line 219,
> in _call_with_frames_removed   File
> "/home/xxx/airflow/utilities/xxx/common/insert_obj.py", line 3, in
>
> from common.xxxxx import Class_name ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common' [2021-05-30 23:13:05,933] {plugins_manager.py:226}
> ERROR - Failed to import plugin
> /home/xxxx/airflow/utilities/xxxxx/common/dag_file.py

I have tried below configs inside may airflow.cfg but always the same error:
plugins_folder=`/home/xxx/airflow/utilities`

Adding a parent directory inside Airflow folder called plugins with an `__init__.py` file and copying utilities inside that:
`plugins_folder=/home/xxx/airflow/plugins`

Comment: could you spread the folder structure a bit along the y axis? The 'dags_conf' and 'utilities' directories are overlapping the 'dags' sub-structure, making it hard to understand. Just moving the whole 'dags' node to the right would help

Comment: What do you mean by 'when I try to list'? What method / command are you using?

Comment: There are 3 main folders: Dags/dags_config/utilities. I needed to use sub directories inside the utilities :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

confirm how the environment variables that Airflow uses or the airflow.cfg settings are configured.

**environment variables**

```
AIRFLOW_HOME=<YOUR_PROJ>
AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER=$AIRFLOW_HOME/dags
AIRFLOW__CORE__PLUGINS_FOLDER=$AIRFLOW_HOME/utilities
```

**airflow.cfg**

```
dags_folder = {AIRFLOW_HOME}/dags
plugins_folder = {AIRFLOW_HOME}/utilities
```

Also, see what is configured in **PYTHONPATH**:

```
import sys
from pprint import pprint

pprint(sys.path)

# [
#  '/ssddisk/project_name/dags',
#  '/ssddisk/project_name/config',
#  '/ssddisk/project_name/utilities',
#  ...
#  ]
```

See documentation for more details: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/custom-operator.html#creating-a-custom-operator

Comment: The issue was resolved a few weeks ago but Python path was exactly the needed thing :)

Comment: My plugins folder is `{AIRFLOW_HOME}/plugins`. Is it supposed to be `utilities`?

Comment: @RicardoFrancois, they were customized folders from my company actually not default ones.